# Is there any difference between the Comma style and the Number format with commas and 2 decimals?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to emulate the Comma style in Excel 2010.

From what I can tell, this appears to be the same as having the Number format set with "Decimal Places" set to 2 and the "Use Thousands Separator" checked.

Are there any other subtle differences I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in internationalization between the two formats. Excel will handle this automatically.

Some actual differences are

1. The comma style puts a "-" for a value of 0.
2. The comma style uses parentheses for negative values.
3. The comma style has different spacing.

The following represents these differences

```
  Comma  |Number with thousands separator
1,000.00 |                       1,000.00
   10.00 |                          10.00
      -  |                           0.00
 (10.00) |                         -10.00
```

If you want to specify the comma style as a number format you can use the custom string

```
"_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* \"\" - \"\"??_);_(@_)"
```